# Delete an array column, and change position of two columns

Tags: excel, vba

So let's say i have and 4x4 array of various numbers.

I want to delete the third array column, and switch positions of the second and fourth columns within the array.

The ultimate goal is copying information from a sheet into an array, and prepping the array to paste into another sheet.

How would I be able to do this?

```
Sub test()
Dim Arr as variant
Arr=Sheets("Worksheet").Range("A1:D4")
'Delete third column
'Switch second and what was the fourth but now is the 3rd column.
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 4)) = Arr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete 'n' Switch Column in Array

The code overwrites the third column with data from the second column, and at the same time overwrites the second column with data from the fourth column. Finally the last (fourth) column is removed.

```vb
Sub deleteAndSwitch()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim Data As Variant, i As Long
    Data = wb.Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("A1:D4").Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        Data(i, 3) = Data(i, 2)
        Data(i, 2) = Data(i, 4)
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To UBound(Data), 1 To 3)
    'e.g.
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") _
      .Resize(UBound(Data), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Your code works great, is there a way to make it more modular? Basically, the sheet I will be working on will have 30 columns and 500ish rows. I will need to move around many columns and delete about 5-10 columns. Overwriting columns and ReDim the last column out of the array may be a difficult task for a larger sheet. Again, the answer you've given works great, I am just trying to see if there is a way to integrate it into a larger scale. Thanks!

Comment: @M B: I would say that the logic behind the code is clear enough. Enough „modular” if this sounds better... :) It is not something standard. Would you all the time switch the same columns? If not, you must write the code  in a way to follow your switching logic/need... And something else: When somebody spend some times and post an answer answering your question, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works...

Comment: Here is a `Must See` column deleting code by [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308577/array-processing-vba/61309712#61309712) which will shed a light on deleting any column and probably more. But the switching is a little tricky, but you can ask a question for each problem you encounter. Good luck.

Comment: @MB: After thinking about your problem I would suggest you watch at least the first of the videos in this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7ScsebMq5uV493VqnVEIY35SKxUKwWHM). I think this is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 4):

**Alternative via `Application.Index()` function**

For the sake of the art an approach **without loops** allowing to
get any new column order defined just by listing the new column positions via

```
     Array(1, 4, 2)
```

in other words

- the 1st column,
- (the 3rd one omitted=deleted),
- the remaining columns 4 and 2 in switched order*.

*Btw it would even be possible to repeat columns, just insert its number at any position in the column array, e.g. to repeat a date column with changed formatting (assuming date in column 4 e.g. via `Array(1, 4, 4, 2)`*

```
Sub DeleteAndSwitch()
'[1]get data
    Dim data: data = Sheet1.Range("A1:D4")
'[2]reorder columns via Array(1, 4, 2), i.e. get 1st column, 4th and 2nd column omitting the 3rd one
'   (evaluation gets all existing rows as vertical 2-dim array)
    data = Application.Index(data, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) & ")"), Array(1, 4, 2))
'[3]write to any target
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data
End Sub
```

**Related link**

See [Some peculiarities of the the `Application.Index()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Comment: Wonderful. I've seen this in Excel formulas but I have only recently seen this approach in VBA mostly on [VBA for Smarties](https://www.snb-vba.eu/index_en.html) where, among others I found how to create an array of all files in all folders and all sub folders in one(ish) line of code. This is really a treat, one of the top solutions to solve OP's issues.Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Nice! Voted it up. I can slice a 2D array, I can eliminate column, reorder columns, but I cannot insert a column(s) slice in such an array... In fact, I can do it using iteration, but did you find a similar way to **insert** such a vertical slice?

Comment: Let me think it over later, theoretically there could be a chance - @FaneDuru

Comment: Appreciate your perfect interest in getting to the bottom of methods and approaches. - Therefore I tried to give a (partial) answer to your question how to **insert** vertical slices via a separate Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722676/insert-vertical-slices-into-array/62722677#62722677) - @FaneDuru

Comment: I can't get this working; statement[2] data=... causes the Run Time Error #2015.         Also, if I put a Breakpoint at statement [2] and run "? Evaluate..." in the Immediate Window it causes the same Error.                                                                       I can "Read" a Single Row by substituting the Evaluate... Parameter expression with the Row Number.                                                                                             Any Clues please?

Comment: @mikebinz Thx for feedback, but I don't get *any* errors. - Are there changes in the code? Would you please verify the code or communicate it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this issue is to use a better structure than an array.  E.g a dictionary of arrays (Collection, Scripting.Dictionary, Arraylist, jagged array).  So instead of reading a two dimensional section of a spreadsheet into an array, iterate over the columns and add each column as an array to a dictionary.  You can then set up a second simpler dictionary to map each current index to its new index.  No need to delete anything as you will only copy back, column array by column array, those columns you actually need.

Comment: Can you provide a coded example of your approach? I am not familiar with the VBA dictionary method. Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service.  You have been pointed to a possible solution.  You now have a learning opportunity.  I'd suggest starting by looking up VBA collections.

Comment: Why would it be the best way? After processing an array you can simple drop the processing result in a range. So, what arguments do you have when considering such a way being the best? :)

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get T.M.'s answer working. Try this instead. It may looks a little lengthy, but this is because it's mostly (delete-able) Comments.

```
Public mDataO() As String
    
    Function _
ShuffledColA(iRa As Range, iCOcsv As String, ocDSa() As String) As Boolean
    
    'Returns ocDSa as a 1-Based Dynamic String Array of iRa's Values,
    '   with it's Columns Shuffled
    
    'iCOcsv specifies which Columns to Return, and in which Order.
    '   eg ShuffledColA(Selection,"3,1",mDataO) returns Columns 1 & 3
    '       of the Selection, with Columns 1 & 3 Transposed
    
    'Fails and leaves ocDSa Empty if        
    '   iRa is Nothing                      Or
    '   iCOCsv is Null                      Or
    '   Any Field in iCOCsv Is Non-Numeric  Or
    '           "           is Not >=1 And <=the NO iRa Columns
    
    'iCOcsv may include Repeated Column Numbers eg "1,1" will return
    '   2 Copies of Column 1
    
    Dim zCOa, zRowA             'Column Order and Row Variant Arrays
    Dim zR As Long, zC As Long  'Loop Row and Columns
    
    On Error GoTo FailL
    
    zCOa = Split(iCOcsv, ",")   'NB zCOa is 0-Based; the rest are 1-Based
    ReDim ocDSa(1 To iRa.Rows.Count, 1 To UBound(zCOa) + 1)

    For zR = 1 To iRa.Rows.Count
        zRowA = Application.Index(iRa, zR, zCOa)
        For zC = 0 To UBound(zCOa)
            If zCOa(zC) < 1 Or zCOa(zC) > iRa.Columns.Count Then _
                GoTo FailL
            ocDSa(zR, zC + 1) = CStr(zRowA(zC + 1)): Next: Next
    
    If Not Not ocDSa Then
        ShuffledColA = True
    Else
FailL:
        Erase ocDSa: End If: End Function
```

Comment: Thx for feedback, but I don't get *any* errors. - Are there changes in my code? Would you please verify the code or communicate it?

Comment: No; I copied the above code verbatim without changing it into a new Workbook with nothing else running in Excel Pro 2013 on Win7

Comment: Possibly [Error 2015](https://www.errorvault.com/en/troubleshooting/runtime-errors/microsoft/microsoft-excel/error-2015_excel-error-2015) citing: *"Runtime errors are generally caused by incompatible programs running at the same time. It may also occur because of memory problem, a bad graphics driver or virus infection. Whatever the case may be, the problem must be resolved immediately to avoid further problems. Here are ways to remedy the error."* ? @mikebinz